# Detect if user stop typing Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create something like isTyping or not, so I have to detect when user stop type more or less 3 seconds, so I can do my stuff, I allready detected when he's typing using this :

```
     ngOnChanges(searchValue: string) {
    if (!this.searchChangeObserver) {
      Observable.create(observer => {
        this.searchChangeObserver = observer;
      }).debounceTime(3000) 
        .subscribe((data) => {
          if (data) {
            typingStuff();
          }
          else {
            notTypingStuff();
          }
        });
      this.searchChangeObserver.next(searchValue);
    }
  }
}
```

So now I have to detect when user stops typing to do the notTypingStuff();

Is there a simple way to do it?

**EDIT**

I'm also using this :

```
constructor(){
    this.modelChanged
      .debounceTime(300)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        if (data) {
          typingStuff();
        }
        else {
          notTypingStuff();
        }
      });
}
```

But should know when user stops to type in 3 seconds to do the `notTypingStuff()` as well..

Comment: it would be something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/francescov/FYkYE/ in Angular 2?

Comment: How about using `ngModel` and it's methods `ng-dirty` and `ng-pristine`? You can read about it in Angular's docs: https://angular.io/guide/forms#track-control-state-and-validity-with-ngmodel

Comment: @Haseoh looks good, could you post an answer with an example? :)

Answer (score 11):

For the not typing stuff you could create an observable from the input event and set the debaunce time:

HTML:

```
<input #yourElement [(ngModel)]="yourVar"/>
```

Component:

```
@ViewChild('yourElement') yourElement: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    Observable.fromEvent(this.yourElement.nativeElement, 'input')
        .map((event: Event) => (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value)
        .debounceTime(3000)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .subscribe(data => notTypingStuff());
}
```

This way your method will only be executed 3000 after the input is modified, or in other words after the user stops typing.

**EDIT: Angular 9 w/ RxJS 6.5.4**

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    fromEvent(this.yourElement.nativeElement, 'input')
      .pipe(map((event: Event) => (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value))
      .pipe(debounceTime(3000))
      .pipe(distinctUntilChanged())
      .subscribe(data => notTypingStuff());
  }
```

Comment: Nice but how can I reset the current debounceTime when the user restart typing ?

Comment: Elegant and nice solution!
Using Angular 9, I had to wrap map(), debounceTime() and distinctUntilChanged() with pipes for this to work correctly

Comment: @An-droid that is debounceTime works. It restarts. auditTime will not restart timer.

Comment: Why so many pipes? you can simply put one pipe and comma between map, debounceTime and distinctUntilChanged. by the way, this should be the accepted answer. great job.

Answer (score 9):

Angular Version 6.

HTML:

```
<input matInput type="text" (keyup)="searchInterest()" [(ngModel)]="keyword" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
```

COMPONENT:

```
public searchInterest() {
    let wordSearch = this.keyword;
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (wordSearch == this.keyword) {
            if (this.keyword) {
                //função que irá retornar sua lista de objetos
            }else{
                //code here
            }
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: função que irá retornar sua lista de objetos => 
function that will return your list of objects

Answer (score 2):

I would access the (keyup) event on the element the user is typing and check if the time after the event was fired is >= 3s.

Comment: yes but the thing is that everytime I type I have to make an api call and if I want to remove the text it will call also the api because return is also a key....

Answer (score 0):

i think this can work too.

```
COMPONENT.ts

doYourStuff: any = null;
isTyping: boolean = false;

updateTyping(event){

    this.isTyping = true;

    clearTimeOut(this.doYourStuff);

    this.doYourStuff = timeOut( ()=>{
          this.isTyping = false;
    }, 3000);

}

COMPONENT.HTML

<input (keyup)="updateTyping($event)">
```